# Distributed Locking with Zookeeper for Quartz Task

Tags: spring, kubernetes, quartz-scheduler, apache-zookeeper

To solve this problem, [How to run quartz task on single pod in kubernetes cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75059425/how-to-run-quartz-task-on-single-pod-in-kubernetes-cluster)

I got to know that zookeeper would be the good choice in order order to prevent quartz tasks executing on all running kubernetes pods for a spring mvc application (currently getting executed on every pod)

I've created the config as below

```
@Configuration
public class ZookeeperConfig {

    @Bean
    public CuratorFramework client() {
        CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(10.200.XX.XX:2181, new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3));
        client.start();
        return client;
    }

}
```

and have autowired in my QuartzTask class which is extended by every Task available in my application.

```
@Autowired
CuratorFramework client;

@Override
public final void execute() throws TaskException {
    executionThread = Thread.currentThread();
    String taskName = getTaskName();

    try {
        InterProcessMutex lock = new InterProcessMutex(client, "/admintasks");
        if ( lock.acquire(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) )
        {
            try
            {
                LOG.info("Lock acquired, executing task");
                execute(taskName);
            }
            finally
            {
                lock.release();
                LOG.info("Task executed, lock released");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception while trying to execute task with name :: "+taskName, e);
    }
}
```

I've tested my application and checked that task is still getting executed on every pod.
I need the task to be executed only once on any of available pods and not on all the pods.

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done, is you have made sure that task won't be executed in parallel but I expect that your quartz config is using RAMJobStore, so each instance of Quartz acts as a single entity, so every instances will run the job and it will just wait for the lock.

What you can do is:

- make `lock.acquire` with a very short timeout - get or fail. It is not very reliable for fast tasks, but if task is long enough, you can get the parameters that it will work well.
- [select the leader](https://curator.apache.org/docs/getting-started/#leader-election) from all of the instances and run the jobs only on that instance.